# Same blockhash that appears more times in a bitcoind’s rpc call listsinceblock transaction returned json

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, json-rpc, deposit

Let's suppose that listsinceblocks return a json like this:

```
{
"transactions": [
    {
        "involvesWatchonly": true,
        "account": "",
        "address": "mzzg8fvHXydKs8j9D2a8t7KpSXpGgAnk4n",
        "category": "receive",
        "amount": 7.44,
        "label": "",
        "confirmations": 1,
        "blockhash": "f40bdab26258ff30055f90214a24fc6dcea57462535077f3c5789406e0e30072",
        "blockindex": 16,
        "blocktime": 1627657948873,
        "txid": "084752097be80c9291d554601670dc2fc265ac36ef1023519ceb8ff0b4e4995f",
        "vout": 17,
        "walletconflicts": [],
        "time": 1627657911993,
        "timereceived": 1627657911993,
        "bip125-replaceable": "no"
    },
    {
        "involvesWatchonly": true,
        "account": "",
        "address": "mzzg8fvHXydKs8j9D2a8t7KpSXpGgAnk4n",
        "category": "receive",
        "amount": 7.13,
        "label": "",
        "confirmations": 1,
        "blockhash": "f40bdab26258ff30055f90214a24fc6dcea57462535077f3c5789406e0e30072",
        "blockindex": 44,
        "blocktime": 1627657948873,
        "txid": "993c802d705255ebfc08f4642f6f676b64a4864700d7a00d15d89ca61c5333a9",
        "vout": 58,
        "walletconflicts": [],
        "time": 1627657929474,
        "timereceived": 1627657929474,
        "bip125-replaceable": "no"
    }]}
```

Having two transactions with the same blockhash and same address. What this means? Are those two separate deposits with 7.44 and 7.13 btc, ore it is considered like a one deposit of 7.44+7.13 btc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the txid differs it represents two different transactions in the same block.

Comment: Even if the txids were identical, you could say think of it as two separate payments. In the end, this distinction shouldn't matter - what matters is how much you've received on which address.